# How to design large table in HTML/Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I've table which displays around 100 records on button click in a div. It comes in a single page so to reach the end, have to scroll down to earth.

It feels messy and i would like if i can make 10 records on first look and next 10 on next page and so...

Somewhat like

[image]

Is it possible or any alter way to achieve it????

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: whoa whow...exactly what i thought was implemented there...thnks mate

Comment: @Manoz
Can't we implement same using css instead of other party???

Comment: No, you would need client side scripts for this. This can't be done with css standalone.

Comment: oh..okay...thnks a lot...gna learn new thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have also started learning AngularJs recently.
If you want to use AngularJs then you could get some help from this link.
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ . While doing R&D on AngularJs I found this link. Hope this could be helpful.
In order to user ng-grid you can either git checkout or download the zip (or use bower) from here https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/tree/2.x